# How to test the android.max_aspect for Galaxy S8

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-testing

According to this https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html

I need to set max_aspect. There is still no S8 device for the emulator so I set the 5.8" with 2960 x 1440 resolution in the hardware profile.
My app looks OK, without setting the maz_aspect, it fills the screen without black lines as shown in the google article.

How can I test the new 2.1 ration?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442589/android-testing-app-on-galaxy-s8-or-lg-g6

Comment: You can test your app with real S8 device remotely here
http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action?os=101#

Answer (score 0):

You can set your targetSdkVersion = 24,The default is already available.